# Duplicate symbol --- Difference between definition and declaration

Tags: c++, header, duplicates, include, symbols

### Problem

I'm new to C++, and I'm doing a homework problem that plots various distributions in the console, but my project won't compile.  When I had everything in the same file, it all worked fine and dandy, but my professor wants us to split things up into an hpp file, a cpp file and a main file.  I just moved everything over and now it won't compile due to a duplicate symbol error.

### Definition vs. Declaration

I understand that you want to only include declarations of functions in your header file, so I added those but kept the actual definitions of the functions in the cpp file.  I have an include statement in the cpp file which is including the header file and another one in main.cpp which including the cpp file.
I understand that my problem may have something to do with my include statements, but I'm lost on how to fix it.

#### distributions.hpp

This file is the class definition and the declarations of the four functions I wrote

```
#include <iostream>

class DistributionPair
{
  public:
    DistributionPair(std::uint32_t minValue, std::uint32_t maxValue) :
        minValue(minValue),
        maxValue(maxValue),
        count(0)
    {
    }

    std::uint32_t minValue;
    std::uint32_t maxValue;
    std::uint32_t count;
};

std::vector<DistributionPair> generateUniformDistribution(std::uint32_t, std::uint32_t, std::uint32_t, std::uint8_t);
std::vector<DistributionPair> generateNormalDistribution(std::uint32_t, float, float, std::uint8_t);
std::vector<DistributionPair> generatePoissonDistribution(std::uint32_t, std::uint8_t, std::uint8_t);
void plotDistribution(std::string, const std::vector<DistributionPair>&, const std::uint8_t);
```

#### distributions.cpp

This file contains the rest of the definitions of those four functions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <random>
#include "distributions.hpp"

std::vector<DistributionPair> generateUniformDistribution(std::uint32_t howMany, std::uint32_t min, std::uint32_t max, std::uint8_t numBins)
{......
```

#### main.cpp

This is the main function that plots the distributions

```
#include <iostream>
#include "distributions.cpp"

int main()
{......
```

#### Error Messages

The following is the error message that I get when I'm compiling my code:

```
duplicate symbol 'generateUniformDistribution(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned char)' in:
    /Users/ryanegbert/Desktop/c++/assign2/build/RandDistributions.build/Debug/RandDistributions.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/distributions.o
    /Users/ryanegbert/Desktop/c++/assign2/build/RandDistributions.build/Debug/RandDistributions.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
..........

ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I use an `#include "distributions.hpp"` then I get a different compile error:

```
/Users/ryanegbert/Desktop/c++/assign2/main.cpp:6:20: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::vector<DistributionPair, std::__1::allocator<DistributionPair> >'
    auto uniform = generateUniformDistribution(100000, 0, 79, 40);
```

since my functions are being defined in distributions.cpp.

I am using Xcode v11.0 on Mac.

Does anyone have any help on why I may be getting this compile errors?

Comment: Please show the exact error message from your compiler (a [mre])

Comment: If you're asking about errors. one would think the actual *errors* are relevant. So, I don't understand why you wrote a well-formed post, but completely omitted the very thing you're questioning. Please include the *exact* error messages *verbatim* in your question, and note an mentioned line numbers, etc, with inline code comments. Likely related to that, including .cpp files in .cpp files is fundamentally flawed. Your .cpp files should include .h headers, your build command(s) should compile each .cpp file, and the link phase should stitch it all together.

Comment: In main, try `#include "distributions.hpp"` instead of `#include "distributions.cpp"`

Comment: I added the error message that it gives me when I try to compile.

Comment: When I try to ```#include "distributions.hpp"``` I'm missing the actual definition of the function, so it won't compile like that either.

Comment: Please update the question what is the error message if you include `.hpp` instead of `.cpp`. And what are the commands you use to build the program.

Comment: This is not a linking error anymore. Maybe you're just missing a `#include <vector>` from `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note it is a **linker** error, not a compiler one.

Think the executable building as a two-stage process.

- On first stage, the *compiler* reads source code and generates .o files.
- On second stage, the *linker* reads .o (and other) files and generates executable files.

The .o files have both binary code and symbol references. The compiler generates two kind of things: binary code with the functions *defined*, and symbol references with the functions *declared but not defined*. The linkers task is to solve all references, i.e. associate all symbol references with binary code, to build a complete executable file.

What seems to happen in your example is that your building scripts are doing the following:

- Compile 'main.cpp' + 'distributions.cpp' (included) into 'main.o'
- Compile 'distributions.cpp' into 'distributions.o'
- Link together 'main.o' + 'distributions.o' into the final executable

That way, the linker has two copies of the compiled code from distributions.cpp, one in main.o and the other in distributions.o

To solve it, you have to do one of these:

- Instruct the linker to only use 'main.o' for creating the executable file

or,

- Replace *#include "distributions.cpp"*  by  *#include "distributions.hpp"* so that your main.o file will contain only the symbol references, and the linker will glue together symbols and code from *distributions.o* into the executable file.

Comment: Linking main.o only and keeping `#include "distributions.cpp"` defeats the purpose of splitting the source into separate files.

Comment: Thank you.  I obviously didn't know the difference between a compile error and a linker error.  Once I changed it so that the linker only referenced 'main.o' instead of all three of the files, it seemed to work fine.

Comment: @stormblessed97: then you choose the wrong solution. Unless you want to learn what a unity build is, but it's very improbable.

Comment: @geza like I said above, I'm super new to C++ and I honestly am just trying to get this assignment to run correctly.

Comment: @stormblessed97: all right. If that's your last assignment, and you don't care about C++, then it's fine. But if you have more assignments, then I think that you should understand things, and you should do things as you supposed to do. Including `.cpp` defeats the whole purpose of separate files. It works like if you just copied the contents of the `.cpp` into `main.cpp` by hand. The point is here to compile `distributions.cpp` and `main.cpp` separately into one-one object file, then link these object files together.

Comment: @geza I'll go look up a tutorial on splitting c++ projects into separate files to understand.  Although I would prefer most any other language, I do think it is good to learn.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must `#include "distributions.hpp"` in main.cpp instead of `#include "distributions.cpp"`, but you also must include all headers your function prototype depends on in the beginning if `"distributions.hpp"`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
```

Comment: The problem is that when I ```#include "distributions.hpp"```, I get a different error that I referenced in my original post.

Comment: The error you are getting (`implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::vector<DistributionPair,...`) is because you did not `#include <vector>` in `"distributions.hpp"`. Your professor will not give you full credit if you follow the other answer.